# Receiving Query String in PHP

Tags: php, wampserver

I am writing code for a simple `WAMP server`. It would receive a query string from another machine and simply display the parameters after parsing.

How **would the server know that a query string has been received**? And when received, **how would it perform desired action on the query string**?

Edit: The parameters are being passed as URL.

Comment: Your Question is not clear.

Comment: Query string always come with URL so you will get query string in`$_GET` variable

Comment: `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['foo'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the superglobal variable `$_GET`.

For example, at the URL `http://example.com/foo.php?bar=BAM`, the variable `$_GET['bar']` has the value `BAM`.

You can check whether there are any query string variables by seeing if `count($_GET) > 0`.

To check whether a parameter is set, you can do something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['bar'])) {
    // do something cool
} else {
    echo "Hey, you didn't give me a value for bar!";
}
```

---

Edit: If you are passing it in some other way, not in the URL, then please clarify your question. How you access the data will obviously depend on how you receive it.

Comment: And if you are not sure which requestmethod is used, you can substitute `$_GET` with `$_REQUEST`

Comment: @RichardBernards Right, although I think OP is using "query string" to mean the [URL query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Comment: @RichardBernards It doesn't matter which request method is used, because the query string is always represented by `$_GET`.

Comment: @Jack and Ed: a query string is just a stringified representation of the request variables. Doesn't matter which HTTP method is used. Webservers and the likes use the words query string to just identify `$_GET` parameters because they are primarily dealing with the url.

Comment: @RichardBernards I understand your point, and yes, data is also passed in the same format for POST and other requests. My point is that it sounds like the OP is asking about the GET data, i.e., the URL query string.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have two URLs:

```
www.example.com
www.example.com?param=Jonas
```

Now in first url you have no parameters, while second has parameter `param` that value is `Jonas`.

In PHP parameters usually are passed via POST or GET requests. They are stored to `$_POST` or `$_GET` (depending on request type). So to get something form GET request (every parameter in URL) you use:

```
if (!empty($_GET['param'])) {
    echo $_GET['param']; // will echo 'Jonas'
}
```